# How to access the next element and check if it has a particular class

Tags: jquery

I need to call a function based on whether the second following `td` element has a certain class.

Here is the HTML

```
<tr id="939">
  <td data-id="939">Test2</td>
  <td class="hold" data-id="939"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="938">
  <td data-id="938">Test1</td>
  <td class="someotherclass" data-id="938"></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the JQuery function

```
$('body').on('click', '#article td:first-child', function(e){

    // I need to check the next td for the hold class
    if($(this).next().hasClass(".hold")){
    // Call my function
    }
});
```

How do I do this? I've tried using `next` and `closest` but that yields nothing.

**EDIT:**

I've made a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NDXBb/

Comment: `hasClass(".hold")` should be `hasClass("hold")` (remove the dot).

Comment: Thank you. I just tried that and I still get nothing back. I guess I was close. :)

Comment: you should post some fiddle demo, we don't see the whole HTML structure here, also it's not clear on what's not working here.

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GzK5m/) once you remove the `.`.

Comment: You're right, there is more code. I can post if need be. Would it matter that this `if` condition is inside a `$.getJSON` function?

Comment: Why would it be inside a `getJSON` function? Yes, that probably makes an enormous difference.

Comment: OK, I am calling data from the server and then doing something with the values. I need to test against these values and is why I'm trying to do this inside the `getJSON` function

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you with it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: No problem. Where should I post it?

Comment: Do I need a new fiddle or can I update the one Blazemonger made?

Comment: Here is the complete function http://jsfiddle.net/NDXBb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` does not refer to your td class but your `getJSON`. Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#article td:first-child', function(e){
    $nextObj = $(this).next();

    //YOUR getJSON function

       if($nextObj.hasClass("hold")){
          // Call my function
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks GGio. I tried this and it's not working. What the console shows for `$nextObj` is `jQuery[]`

Comment: GGio, can you please tell me why what I originally had inside the getJSON function wouldn't work?

Comment: @NaN because $(this) within getJSON function does not refer to the click event but it refers to the getJSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#article td:first-child").click(function() {

    if($(this).next().hasClass("hold")){
        console.log("works");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RRFj3/

Comment: Joe, this isn't working. This is exactly what I already have.

Comment: I did not see your comment about the JSON function. The posted fiddle just simplified the use case. :)

Comment: Yeah, I've got to use Fiddle more often. I just thought this would be a fast solution.